# Input parameters hard coded in Stored procedure call

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure. This procedure is called as part of my java web application flow.

I have hard coded input parameters in the Call query itself

For example:

```
Connection.prepareCall(
    "CALL ABCDEF.XYZ('ABCDEF','ereefgw','f','h',?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

First four are input parameters. Can i pass input parameters in this way?

I am getting exception with error code -440.

Can anyone help me in letting know how to pass hard coded parameters to a stored procedure call

Comment: what web application java or asp?

Comment: chk this out http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-in-parameter-example/

Comment: I want to hard code the input parameters in the CALL stored procedure query itself

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: What database is this?  -440 is only meaningful for a particular database vendor.

Comment: SQLException with SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: Database we are using DB2

Comment: The parameters you are specifying don't align with the expected inputs.  Are you using the right parameter numbers for the bind variables?